# JIRA custom fields values from remote app REST API

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Is it possible to retrieve data from external REST API (in my case a zabbix server API) into JIRA (cloud version) inside a multi-choice input ?

the user should choose a list of monitored machines when creating an issue.

I think that i need to develop something like nfeed plugin that is not available in the cloud version. need to be sure that it's possible before starting.

The Issue creation is done in Atlassian service desk portal.

Answer (score 0):

From browsing through the Atlassian Documentation it does **not** appear you can at this time develop your own addon and add it into an Atlassian Cloud JIRA instance.

This would of been the solution to your problem and from looking at the available addons for JIRA Cloud it does not appear that any resolve your need.

Your only option would be to potentially wrap the Atlassian Service Desk Portal in your own page that has the required fields for JIRA available and the required fields pulled in from Zabbix and then upon submission creates the issue in JIRA using its REST API. (See [Atlassian Connect](https://connect.atlassian.com/))